# Linear combination of inconsistent b and consistent b in Ax = b

Tags: linear-algebra

It's a trivial problem but I'm not sure if my proof is valid it's number 13d in the following link: http://www.math.upenn.edu/ugrad/calc/m240/240la.pdf

For (a,b,c) = (0,0,1) you can trivially show the system is inconsistent by using row reduction, but I'm trying to utilize the hint. I wrote a proof using the hint, but I'm having lingering doubts if what I wrote is entirely correct.

Edited out what I had. I had very confusing notation and was treating the b's as x's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is fine but I think this is what you meant. 
Let $(1,2,4) = u$, $(1,2,3) = v$ and $(0,0,1) = w$. Then $u - v = w$. Now assume there exists $r$ such that $Ar = w$. We have already shown that there is $p$ such that $Ap = u$. Hence $Ap - v = Ar$ i.e. $v = A(p-r)$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I think that was what was confusing me.